# Finding partial matches in an href tag

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to use Beautiful Soup to find all `<a>` elements where the `href` attribute includes a certain string.

An example of the full element is:

```
<a href="/markets/NZSX/securities/ABA">ABA</a>
```

I am looking for all elements where `href` includes `"/markets/NZSX/securities/"`.

I am looking to extract the **text** from this element. This would be `ABA` in the example.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve that. With [`.find_all()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all):

```
soup.find_all("a", href=re.compile(r"^/markets/NZSX/securities/"))
soup.find_all("a", href=lambda href: href and href.startswith("/markets/NZSX/securities/"))
```

Or, with a [CSS selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
soup.select('a[href^="/markets/NZSX/securities/"]')
```

The above would check for the `href` to *start with* `/markets/NZSX/securities/`. If you want apply the "contains" check instead:

```
soup.find_all("a", href=re.compile(r"/markets/NZSX/securities/"))
soup.find_all("a", href=lambda href: href and "/markets/NZSX/securities/" in href)
soup.select('a[href*="/markets/NZSX/securities/"]')
```

Comment: Great answer! Note that this assumes one wants the href to *begin* with the string, rather than *include* the string as the OP mentioned.

Comment: Thanks alexce. One more thing; this returns the full element i.e. "<a href ...".  How would this change so that only the text from the element is returned. In the example this would be ABA

Comment: @datavoredan sure, just iterate over the results and call `get_text()`. For example: `[elm.get_text() for elm in soup.find_all("a", href=re.compile(r"^/markets/NZSX/securities/"))]`

Answer (score 0):

To extend the very helpful answer written by alecxe, I was also able to find classes that begin with a certain string. This line gets age from Wikipedia:

```
soup.find('table' , class_=lambda class_: class_ and class_.startswith("infobox")).find('th', string="Born")
```