# Find an HTML element using BeautifulSoup by partial text

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have to find all paragraph that contains a specific partial text.

I find to find it that way
Whole text in paragraph is

```
"Open Until: Tuesday November 20, 2018, // 4:00 pm MST"
```

There is always a new date each time, so i have to give partial text like

```
element = soup.findAll("p",text="Open Until")
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34759142/7832176

Answer (score 2):

You haven't shared the relevant html elements for that portion, so it is hard to provide you with any solution. However, `text="Open Until"` doesn't work that way. It only looks for the full text not partial. Try like below instead.

```
for item in soup.find_all("p"):
    if not "Open Until" in item.text:continue
    print(item.text)
```